# scrapy: extract property from a selector

Tags: python, scrapy

I am sorry for the beginner question but this is driving me crazy:

Imagine I have this selector to a group of span elements:

```
ori=response.xpath("//div[@class='comparison- 
  row']//div[contains(@class,'modern- 
  translation')]//span[contains(@class,'line-mapping')]")
```

I need to extract 2 properties, namely the data-id and the text from each span

I do:

```
for r in ori:
    id_n=r.xpath("@data-id").extract()
    text_n=r.xpath("/text()").extract()
    if len(id_n)!=0 and len(text_n)!=0:
       ids.append(id_n)
       text.append(text_n)
```

But the following returns an error:

```
text_n=r.xpath("/text()").extract()
```

I tried:

```
for r in ori:
    n=r.extract()
    print(n)
```

I have this output:

I'll stay at home and pray for God's blessing in your attempt.
 Leave tomorrow, and be sure of this: anything that I can help you with, you shall have.

I need to extract each text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your xpath expression relative to the current element:

```
text_n = r.xpath("./text()").extract()
```

Also, `if len(id_n)!=0 and len(text_n)!=0:` is better written as `if id_n and text_n:`